# How is oracle client different from oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, installation, oracleclient

I am doing installation of an oracle product and it requires an oracle client, and It requires a oracle database.

My confusion here is how does a client differ from database ? I mean in terms of functionality?

Did a research on oracle website but did not find anything convincing. Could someone please provide more insights on this ?

Comment: The client _connects_ to a (running) database server.

Comment: So, what advantage does a client have here, I have a developer tool that can help me connect to the database ? why does oracle have a client ?

Comment: Your "developer tool" needs the client to be able to connect to the server.

Comment: Simple answer is that oracle uses a client-server architecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Answer (score -1):

You don't always need the Oracle client installation. For example SQL developer doesn't.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44470/why-oracle-sql-developer-does-not-need-oracle-client

What you need is some software that helps you make the connection tot the database.

Comment: The JDBC driver essentially replaces the Oracle client software

Comment: Agreed you need "a client". This does not always have to be "the Oracle client software" which in my world is the installation package provided by Oracle. It is unclear to me if that distinction is made by the OP.

Comment: The OP specifically asked "how does *a client* differ from [a] database?"